# Laravel Eloquent to treat the column 'archived_at' like it does 'deleted_at'

Tags: php, class, laravel-4

I'm trying to get Laravel to treat a newly added column called 'archived_at' the same way it treats 'deleted_at'. That is, when I run a query, I don't want it to pick up any archived records unless I expressly tell it so (i.e., Invoices::onlyArchived()->paginate()). In other words, the archived_at behavior should mimic the soft delete behavior built into Laravel.

I see the soft delete functionality built into Laravel's Builder and Model classes. Here's what I have so far:

1. Extend Model class and add archived_at functionality in new
   class.
2. Update app/config.php alias as follows:

> ```
>     // 'Eloquent'        => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
>     'Eloquent'        => 'CoreExtensions\Model',
> ```

I can't seem to figure out how to extend the Builder class and force Laravel to read from the extended Builder class. If I can get that far, I can probably figure out the rest. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You probably need only to extend Eloquent and do something like this:

```
<?php

class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public static function withArchived()
    {
        return with(new static)->newQuery(true, true);
    }

    public static function onlyArchived()
    {
        return with(new static)->newQuery(false, false, true);
    }

    /**
     * Get a new query builder for the model's table.
     *
     * @param  bool  $excludeDeleted
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
     */
    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true, $excludeArchived = true, $onlyArchived = false)
    {
        $builder = $this->newEloquentBuilder($this->newBaseQueryBuilder());

        // Once we have the query builders, we will set the model instances so the
        // builder can easily access any information it may need from the model
        // while it is constructing and executing various queries against it.
        $builder->setModel($this)->with($this->with);

        if ( ! $onlyArchived)
        {
            if ($excludeDeleted && $this->softDelete)
            {
                $builder->whereNull($this->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn());
            }

            if ($excludeArchived)
            {
                $builder->whereNull('archived_at');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $builder->whereNotNull('archived_at');
        }

        return $builder;
    }

}
```

And then you'll probably be able to:

```
Invoices::onlyArchived()->paginate();

Invoices::withArchived()->where('customer_id', $customer_id)->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Laravel 4.2 you can check out these two files, I've created my own traits based on the built-in SoftDelete trait. (It's far more flexible than the answer above.)

- Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingScope.php
- Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingTrait.php

http://laravel.io/forum/08-14-2014-add-filter-to-builder-on-a-custom-method-call

Comment: where did you put your custom files?